# Message from worker to worker in a nodejs cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

When I create a clustered app like

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isWorker) {
  console.log('Worker ' + process.pid + ' has started.');
}

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log('Master ' + process.pid + ' has started.');

  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < require("os").cpus().length; i++) {
    var worker = cluster.fork();
  }
}
```

And then run it with `pm2` in cluster mode

```
pm2 start index.js -i 0
```

My `isMaster` part never runs, I assume this is due to pm2 being the master while starting my app thus it never gets to be master, so here comes the problem. I need to be able to have communication between my workers because they keep websocket connections and that seems like the only way to broadcast stuff. What are the options?

If I run it without cluster mode (`pm2 start index.js`) then everything seems to execute as expected but then I only get a single process in `pm2 list` which is a bummer, if there is a way to get around that and have pm2 display all the child processes separately without using its cluster mode I'd be happy with that solution as well.

Comment: Why do you care about having a single process in pm2 list?, pm2 wraps your code, so you will always be a worker.

Comment: Don't run it in pm2 cluster mode.  Your code creates the cluster.  You don't want pm2 to do that instead of your code.  If you want to see all the processes look in the OS process list, not the pm2 process list.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande because it reports usage and stuff and also logs in different files per process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `process.message` you won't be able to use pm2 cluster mode, since `process.message` sends messages to master.

If you want to use pm2 cluster mode, you have to use another way of communication between workers, such as `Redis`,`RabbitMQ`, `Unix Sockets`.

There are some packages that will allow you to setup an IPC communication very easily, for example: [node-ipc](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc)